# How to query an external csv file uploaded through StringIO in S3 in Snowflake with the right format?

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've written these Python methods in my custom Airflow operator to convert a dictionary to a dataframe then to StringIO object and upload it to S3 as a CSV file without saving locally.

```
    def execute(self, context):
        s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id=self.s3_conn_id)
        retailer, d1 = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(self.data_source)
        self._upload_file(d1, retailer, s3_hook)

    def _upload_to_s3(self, df, s3_hook):
        csv_buffer = StringIO()
        df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
        s3_hook.load_string(string_data=csv_buffer.getvalue(),
                            key=self.s3_key,
                            bucket_name=self.s3_bucket,
                            replace=True)

    def _upload_file(self, d, retailer, s3_hook):
        self.s3_key = f"S3_STAGING/{retailer}/{retailer}_summary.csv"
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
        df.index.name = 'product_code'
        self._upload_to_s3(df, s3_hook)
```

The DAG runs and uploads the file successfully, [and the file looks normal when using S3 query on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2inMZ.png). But when I try to query it in Snowflake:

```
select t.$1 as description,
       t.$2 as parent_company
from @S3_STAGING/S3_STAGING/sample/sample_summary.csv as t
```

[All columns are concatenated into one for some reasons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDKYw.png) Is there any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if you defined a specific field_delimiter for the stage? To be sure, can you create a file format and use it:

> create file format myformat type = 'csv';
>
> select t.$1 as description,
> t.$2 as parent_company from @S3_STAGING/S3_STAGING/sample/sample_summary.csv (file_format =>
> 'myformat') t;